# 960px wide centred div brought into HTML5 Boilerplate extends off screen on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, css-position, html5boilerplate

When my main widthfix div for my 960px wide centred site is brought into HTML5 Boilerplate it misbehaves on iPhone. In Safari on the iPhone the div extends off screen on iPhone. It works fine on my laptop screen browsers & everywhere outside of HTML5 Boilerplate.

I haven't changed anything inside HTML5 Boilerplate yet apart from add a widthfix div with the following class:

```
#widthfix {
    position: relative; 
    width: 960px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

...I've just worked it out it can be corrected by removing:

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"

from the head.

I don't know if this is the best solution, so if anyone has any additional input I'm all ears.

However at least it appears to display OK.